# Deconstructing ios 7 safari app UI

Tags: user-interface, ios7, swift

I am new to iOS 7 coding and trying to create a custom web browser similar to Safari but with a few extra buttons.

I started off trying to add a UIToolbar to the TOP of the view only to discover this is (a) meant for the bottom and (b) does not allow for text fields.  I then explored the search and nav bar objects with no luck.

Can someone explain to me what objects are used to create a toolbar on the TOP of a view, such as in Safari?  Are objects, such as the next, back and search bar just put on the view and positioned or are they in some kind of container that I am not understanding.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good question - I would say iPad.